# Spring Cloud Gateway Only Route to Healthy Instances

Tags: spring, microservices, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm quite new to spring cloud gateway, please bare with me for my ignorance.

I have 1 `spring cloud gateway` at `localhost:8999` and 2 microservice instances named `member`at `localhost:8085` & `localhost:8086`. I also have a service discovery (Spring Cloud Eureka) and using Spring Load Balancer. I have registered all the gateway and application instances through eureka server at `localhost:8761`. Everything works fine and the gateway is able to load balance between both `member` instance using the default load balancing (round robin):

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: custom-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: member-route
          uri: lb://member
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**

server:
  port: 8999
```

If I shutdown 1 of the `member` instance at port `8085`, it seems like spring cloud gateway is not smart enough to detect and still load balances to the instance that is down which result in this error:

[image]

What I would like to know is, are there any way for me to configure the gateway to automatically detect the down instance and only load balances to the healthy instances?